# Intro to Proof Class: Understanding how to interpret $f \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$; $I: A \to \mathbb R$; $I(f) = \int_0^1 f(x) dx$

Tags: solution-verification, learning

I am currently in a intro to proof class, so far I have had a good understanding of proof techniques but after moving onto functions I have become really confused on how to interpret some basic ideas:

For instance, $A=\lbrace f \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} |f\;\text{continuous}\rbrace$  (added this after, sorry for the confusion)

I read this as our domain is the range of values between 0 and 1. Our codomain is any real number. So, we could make functions such as $f(0) = 2, f(0.1) = 100, f(1) = -3$.

Next  $I: A \to \mathbb R$ is given by $I(f) = \int_0^1 f(x) dx$

I read this like our domain is any real number, so $I(f) = \int_0^1 f(x) dx$ means we input a real number we got from $A$, and $f(x)$ is the real number's integral?

So, an example would be $f(0) = 2$, so $I(2) = \int_0^1 f(2) dx$ = $2$?

I ask this because I want to prove surjection and disprove injection, but I am so lost on what these functions CAN and CANNOT do that I can't move onto disproving or proving the statement.

Any advice would be extremely helpful.

Comment: $A$ is a set of *functions* of the form $f:[0, 1] \to \Bbb R$, not a set of numbers.  Constant functions are very probably within that definition, but so are very many non-constant functions such as, for example, $f(x)=3-x$.  What does your book say about the definition of $A$?

Comment: So sorry my mistake @RobertShore, A is the function you are referring to

Comment: Your question is becoming less clear.  You say you want to prove surjection and disprove injection.  Of what map?  I think you're trying to prove that $I$ is surjective but not injective.  $I$ maps a whole set of functions (not just one specific function) into $\Bbb R$.  I'm pretty sure you're calling that set of functions $A$ and the only thing I'm sure of is that the elements of $A$, which are all *functions* (not numbers), are integrable.  That limitation matters because not all functions are integrable.  How, specifically, does your book define $A$?

Comment: @RobertShore, sorry about this, I think I am missing some of the wording to clarify my case. The book shortens the whole function $f$ to $A$ for brevity. I am really confused on how to interpret A. I am understanding it like I can input any value between zero to one, and it will output a real number. So I can input 0, and it will output some real number. Can I input a value between 0 and 1 and the function can output a equation, like $sin(x)$ or $x^2+1$?

Comment: what you have written now, $A=f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is ambiguous. is $A$ just another name for $f$ so that $A(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$? is $A$ the graph of $f$? if it were $A=\{f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}\}$, or $A$ was the space of all integrable functions on $[0,1]$ then it would make more sense, since the domain of $I$ would be the set containing $f$ or the space of all integrable functions on $[0,1]$, respectively. in both cases, the co-domain of $I$ would be the real numbers.

Comment: Hi, A is the set of all functions f:[0, 1] -> R that are continuous on the interval [0,1]. It’s really A that I am getting confused on. So the first of your definitions (I believe). The confusion on my end is how interpret A. What are some examples of A? How do I carry over A into the next function (The function I)? I’m sorry for the vagueness, I’m trying to fit the language to match my question, but I am pretty new to interpreting functions outside of the very general cases used in earlier calculus classes.

Comment: $A$ doesn't have examples.  It's like asking, "What are some examples of the set of real numbers?"  There's only one set of real numbers.  Similarly, there is only one set that contains exactly the continuous functions $f:[0, 1] \to \Bbb R$.  Any function continuous on that interval is a member of that set.  So if you can find any two continuous functions with the same definite integral, you will have proved that $I$ is not injective.  And if for an arbitrary $r \in \Bbb R$ you can find some continuous function whose definite integral is $r$, you will have proved that $I$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with elaborating what $A$ is.

$A$ is a set that consists of all continuous functions $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$. For example $f(x) = x^2$ is in $A$, but

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
-1, & x<0.5 \\
+1, & x\geq 0.5
\end{cases}
$$

is not, because the limit in $0.5$ doesn't exist. So basically $A$ is a collection of all continuous function on given interval.

Now you define $I: A \to \mathbb{R}$, that is often called as a "functional", i.e., a mapping from some set to $\mathbb{R}$. You take an element of your set and send it to some real number via $I$. In your case, you take a function and send it to its definite integral on given interval.

About surjection, let's notice that if $f$ is a *constant* function(e.g. $f(x) = 5$, every $x$ is being sent to $5$) such that $f(x)=c$, then $I(f) = c$. So surjectivity holds: for every real number $c$ you have a function $f(x)=c$ such that $I(f)=c$.

About injection, let's notice that obviously, $I(0) = 0$. Can we find such a function $f \in A$ that $I(f) = 0$? Yes, for example let $f = 2x-1$. We have that $I(f) = \int_0^1 f(x)dx = \int_0^1 (2x-1) dx = x^2 - x + C\big\vert_0^1 = 0$.
Therefore $i$ is not injective: distinct functions are not being mapped to distinct values.

Comment: Paul! Thank you! So I can imagine A as a set that is filled with equations. 
For example $x^2$, $sinx$, $x^{x+1000}$ are all in A. However these equations only can take in values between 0 and 1? 


So when I go to $I$, I am plugging in one element from A (I.e a whole formula that only can take in inputs from 0 to 1) in. I will then output a real number, that number being the definite integral?   Extra Q: we call our examples $f(x)=x$, could I also have formulas in A like $w(x)=x$ or $f(m)=m$?

Comment: @EM93, well, elements of $A$ are [functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)), not [equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation). The first one is a relation between 2 sets: you map one element of a first set to an element of a second set. It has an input and output. But equation is a statement: you say that left hand-side is equals to right hand-side, e.g. if you have 2 _functions_ $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, then the equation is $f(x)=g(x)$, and when one wants to _solve the equation_, it means _to find an appropriate $x$, such that the equality holds_.

Comment: In your case, $A$ is filled with the functions that take elements between 0 and 1. It might be even functions that take any real number, but we are interested only in $[0,1]$ interval. When you go to $I$, you plugging in an element from $A$(which is, again, a function, not an equation, but I think you got the idea and this is just the wrong use of word) and output a real number, that is definite integral. For extra question, this cases are actually the same as $f(x)=x$, you have just renamed it, but the essential is the same: $f, w$ are functions and $x,m$ are variables(numbers in $[0,1]$).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like $A$ is the set of functions from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, at least to me. I say this because $I$ takes a *function* as an input and returns a real number as an output.

<strike>I'm not sure how much analysis you've had up to this point, but the set of functions from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is of a greater *cardinality* than $\mathbb{R}$ itself. That essentially means A is "bigger" than $\mathbb{R}$, so $I$ cannot be injective.</strike>

$I$ is definitely surjective though, take $y\in\mathbb{R}$, then take $f\in A$ such that $f(x)=y$, then $I(f)=y$.

EDIT: $A$ is actually the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, but $I$ is still not injective because $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=2x$ both map to $1$:

$$I(f)=\int_0^11dx=1,\quad \quad I(g)=\int_0^12xdx=1$$

Comment: Not all functions are integrable, so $A$ can't be the entire set of functions $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$.  It's at most the set of integrable functions.  I don't know off the top of my head whether the set of integrable functions (under either Riemann or Lebesgue integration) in fact has larger cardinality than does $\Bbb R$.

Comment: The set of continuous functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is greater than the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$, so the integrable functions are of greater cardinality.

Comment: Any continuous real-valued function on the reals is uniquely determined by its value at the rationals, which are countable.  The set of continuous functions $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @RobertShore Oops, yeah you're correct. Still, we can break injectivity with $f(x)=1$ and $f(x)=2x$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a definite integral. What does a definite integral do? It maps your function to a real number. Think of $I$ as a mapping which takes your function and integrates it from 0 to 1. I'm assuming $A$ is the space of functions $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$. Lets say $f(x) = x$ restricted to $[0, 1]$. Then $I(f) = \int_0^1 x dx = \frac{1}{2}$. However, lets say $g(x) =0$. Then $I(g) = \int_0^1 0 dx = 0$

Comment: Hi @ureui, thanks for the help. What’s confusing me is A. I input a value between 0 and 1 and it outputs a real number? I take that real number and plug it into the integral? I’m so used to a function that maps R to R, that now seeing a function map from 0 to 1 to R confuses me.